# Velocity vector for helical motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, geometry

Problem describes a point particle moving in an upwards helix, with the velocity in the $z$-direction being a constant 3 m/s and circular uniform motion in $xy$-plane along a circle with radius = 6 m and period = 5 s. I've solved for the tangential speed along the circle, getting 7.5 m/s.

In the second part of the question, it asks me to solve for the angle between the horizontal and the particle's velocity vector. In the key, it performs this calculation by setting theta = arctan(3 / 7.5). I'm confused as to why we can treat the tangential speed in a *plane* as the horizontal component of a two dimensional velocity vector. Is it that we ignore direction, since at any point along the helical motion we could draw a 2D velocity vector along an arbitrary set of x and y axes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you actually state the answer. Any tangential vector can be taken as the x-direction. What is really important for the arctan function is that the two vectors are orthogonal to each other. Any vector in the x-y plane will be orthogonal to a vector in the z direction only.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a velocity vector in the xy-plane $v_{\rm x}\hat i + v_{\rm y}\hat j$ of constant magnitude but varying direction and another velocity vector $v_{\rm z} \hat j$ of constant magnitude and direction perpendicular to the xy-plane as shown below

[image]

What you are asked to find is the angle $\theta$ between the velocity vector in the xy-plane $\vec {CB}$ and the resultant vector $\vec {CA}$ which is equal to $v_{\rm x}\hat i + v_{\rm y}\hat j + v_{\rm z}\hat z$.

The magnitudes of the sides of that vector triangle $ABC$ are all constant and so you can use trigonometry to find the required angle $\tan \theta = \frac {AB}{CB}$.